# Get Log for each Jenkins pipeline stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

Anyone know how I can get the separate logs (for each pipeline stage) as the Blue Ocean shows. I need to attach them to Jira but I can not find them.
Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'm doing the same thing with the global pipeline library I'm building. This is good for cases where you just want to email the logs of a particular failed stage. Here's how hope it helps. On the sample pipeline below a job named `test` is executed once (`build #1`)

[image: Sample pipeline]

```
    pipeline {
        agent any
        stages{
            stage("Compile") {
                steps {
                    script {
                        echo "Compiling..."
                    }
                }
            }
            stage("Test") {
                steps {
                    script {
                        echo "Testing..."
                    }
                }
            }
            stage("Build") {
                steps {
                    script {
                        echo "Building..."
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

1. Access the API to see execution details. Notice that each object of this JSON includes the attributes `id` and `result`.
   http://localhost:8080/blue/rest/organizations/jenkins/pipelines/test/runs/1/nodes/

   ```
   [
       {
           *snip*
           "actions": [],
           "displayDescription": null,
           "displayName": "Compile",
           "durationInMillis": 341,
           "id": "6",
           "input": null,
           "result": "SUCCESS",
           "startTime": "2018-11-24T18:14:16.196+0800",
           "state": "FINISHED",
           "type": "STAGE",
           "causeOfBlockage": null,
           "edges": [
           {
               "_class": "io.jenkins.blueocean.rest.impl.pipeline.PipelineNodeImpl$EdgeImpl",
               "id": "15",
               "type": "STAGE"
           }
           ],
           "firstParent": null,
           "restartable": true
       },
       {
           *snip*
           "actions": [],
           "displayDescription": null,
           "displayName": "Test",
           "durationInMillis": 246,
           "id": "15",
           "input": null,
           "result": "SUCCESS",
           "startTime": "2018-11-24T18:14:16.693+0800",
           "state": "FINISHED",
           "type": "STAGE",
           "causeOfBlockage": null,
           "edges": [
           {
               "_class": "io.jenkins.blueocean.rest.impl.pipeline.PipelineNodeImpl$EdgeImpl",
               "id": "24",
               "type": "STAGE"
           }
           ],
           "firstParent": "6",
           "restartable": true
       },
       {
           *snip*
           "actions": [],
           "displayDescription": null,
           "displayName": "Build",
           "durationInMillis": 270,
           "id": "24",
           "input": null,
           "result": "SUCCESS",
           "startTime": "2018-11-24T18:14:17.188+0800",
           "state": "FINISHED",
           "type": "STAGE",
           "causeOfBlockage": null,
           "edges": [],
           "firstParent": "15",
           "restartable": true
       }
   ]
   ```
2. Use `result` to check the status of a stage (`SUCCESS`, `FAILED`, `ABORTED`, etc...)
3. Use `id` to get into a particular stage, for this example the logs of Test stage which has an `id` of `15`.

   http://localhost:8080/blue/rest/organizations/jenkins/pipelines/test/runs/1/nodes/15/log/

   ```
   Testing...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you can find the rest api document through this url:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/blueocean-plugin/tree/master/blueocean-rest

still need to notice this in their document.

```
The Blue Ocean REST API is a "private API" designed for the Blue Ocean user interface. 
It may change without notice at any time.
```